# How to automate the creation of a vCAP user-defined variable in a Bluemix deployment?

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud, alchemyapi, devops

I am trying to create an application in DevOps Services using Alchemy API services. Every time I try to build and deploy the application I need to set the Alchemy_Key in Bluemix Environment Variable.
Is their any option to automate the creation of User-Defined Variable?

Comment: Environment variable settings should persist after a redeploy.  Are you seeing the environment variable getting lost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can automate the creation of a user defined environment variable by adding the following to the manifest.yml file :

```
env:
    ALCHEMY_KEY: ${value}
```

Please look at the following link for additional attributes to be used in manifest.yml for deploying applications : http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html

Thanks.

Comment: I would avoid setting keys and passwords in the manifest.yml because I prefer not to put those things in source control (hard to control their access).

Comment: To avoid exposing keys in manifest.yml, one way is to add a user defined service as explained in Niklas Heidloff's article : http://heidloff.net/nh/home.nsf/article.xsp?id=16.12.2014110019NHEDRA.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the cf CLI command: cf set-env

cf help set-env
NAME:
   set-env - Set an env variable for an app

ALIAS:
   se

USAGE:
   cf set-env APP_NAME ENV_VAR_NAME ENV_VAR_VALUE